# guava-11.0.1.jar and Maven plugin for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, guava, caliper

I created  maven project in Eclipse and added a few dependencies.

Here is a full list of dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.caliper</groupId>
        <artifactId>caliper</artifactId>
        <version>0.5-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then I ran Maven install and all nesssery libs were uploaded.

Next time I got the following message:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building mywebapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ mywebapp ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\WORK_SPASE\mywebapp\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) @ mywebapp ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\WORK_SPACE\mywebapp\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.785s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 31 04:13:10 VET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/121M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project mywebapp: Compilation failure
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\User1\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\11.0.1\guava-11.0.1.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

And   when  I tried to  run  my  class  I  got : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Splitter`

Please  give me a piece of  advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I see that you have an error:

> reading C:\Users\User1.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\11.0.1\guava-11.0.1.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)

which might be caused by a failure during the download of the lib. The solution is to delete the folder C:\Users\User1.m2\repository\com\google and retry the build.

Furthermore I see that you are using an extremely old version of the maven-compiler-plugin (2.0.2) which brings me to the conclusion that you didn't configured your maven-compiler-plugin which means you are using java 1.4 but you need at least 1.5. You have to configure your maven-compiler-plugin like this:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Maybe you have to change to 1.5.

Comment: Hi Frank,  thanks for you reply! I removed the  google  dir, ran  "Maven  Install"   again,  the  dir and  subdirs  were  recreated, all libs were downloaded  as well http://prntscr.com/r1oco
I  use the latest version  of maven plugin which is availible http://prntscr.com/r1nwc
Maven settings - http://prntscr.com/r1noz
JDK - 1.6.027
I have never used  the  Maven  before and  you are  right  that   my version  is older  than  yours. Could  you please  tell me  how can I download the version 3.0? It's not availible via eclipse install, perhaps I write a  wrong search text.
Windows 7(x64) Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's that big of a problem if you use Maven 2.x instead of Maven 3. Frank was talking about the "Maven compiler plugin", which is too old. By adding his XML snippet to your pom.xml file, the right plugin will be used (without needing to install Maven 3).

Comment: Ok thanks,  the building process works fine:) The  last  issue  that  still I get is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Splitter   it's a  part  of google   guava jar, maven downloaded  it and  this  jar is availible in project build path.. I  found another topic on stackoverflow  with  the same  error, but can't understand the  cause  yet.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse Plugin (m2e) you are already using Maven 3. The newest version of Maven is 3.0.4 which can be downloaded [here](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi).

Comment: Have you given a scope for guava?

Comment: Yes:   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
   <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
   <version>11.0.1</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>

Comment: @user341203 Note that I _didn't_ write the answer, I just edited it at some point to add some formatting.

Comment: @user341203 _How_ do you "run your class"? Is the guava jar in the classpath?

Comment: Yes, it's in  the classpath. [link](http://prntscr.com/r21qw). Run  as  simple   java class -   select  class -> run as Java app